# VBA different message box values want to display as single msgbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have one outer for loop which will gives me some status messages in the msgBox. I want to collect each message in such way that it will collect all the msgBox text  and before ending the code i want to display these different messages as single message. May be for loop is beneficial for me. Please any one have some example?

Comment: Please so not post duplicate questions.